# How to retrieve multiple rows with the same ID from two tables with only knowing one value

Tags: mysql

I am sitting at a problem currently. I have imported an open source geolocation database.

I have two tables I want access to.

Table A: 
**ID   | lat | lon**
200 | 48  | 12

Table B:
**ID   | Type  | Value**
200 | City   | Munich
200 | State | Bavaria

Now I want to have a result like this:
**ID   | lat | lon | TypeValue | TypeValue**
200 | 48  | 12  | Munich        | Bavaria

Is this possible in only one query?

EDIT: The only value I know is "Munich"

EDIT2: This is what I've got so far:

```
SELECT 
geodb_coordinates.lat AS lat,
geodb_coordinates.lon AS lon,
geodb_textdata.text_val AS text
FROM 
geodb_coordinates,
geodb_textdata
WHERE 
geodb_coordinates.loc_id = geodb_textdata.loc_id AND
geodb_textdata.text_val LIKE :location
GROUP BY geodb_textdata.text_val
ORDER BY LENGTH(geodb_textdata.text_val)
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible with self join. What have you tried so far? Is the number of records in table B with the same id 2 or can it be more, such as city -> state -> country -> continent?

Comment: You can't have two columns with same name...

Comment: @Shadow what I currently got is, that I can have "ID | lat | lon | TypeValue". No success in getting the other TypeValue. And yes. Table B can have more rows with the same ID.

Comment: Then this question is duplicate of all dynamic pivot questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns)

Comment: @Shadow First time I've ever heard about pivot. Thank you very much! Going to try out the queries ASAP.

Comment: It is quite a common question. The technique is either referred to as pivoting or cross tabulated (crosstab) query. Excel and Access are really great at it, mysql, well, not that good at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
Select A.ID,A.Iat, A.Ion, B.Value as TypeValue1, C.Value as TypeValue2
from 
A inner join B on A.ID=B.ID and B.Type='City'
Inner join B as C on B.ID=C.ID and C.Type='State'
```

Comment: Should be C.Type='State' If there are more than 2 records (see comment from OP), then this query is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
SELECT b1.ID, a.lat, a.lon, b1.Value, b2.Value
FROM table_b as b1 join table_a as a on a.ID=b1.ID, table_b as b2
where b1.ID=b2.ID and b1.`Type`='City' and b2.`Type`='State' and b1.Value='Munich';
```

I guess there is only one city per id, right?